# How to freeze lf-net tensorflow model to use it with opencv dnn?

Tags: python, c++, opencv, tensorflow

i would like to use lf-net models in opencv to compare it with sift and akaze keypoints detector sand descriptors in my application
opencv version : 4.1.2
tensorflow version : 1.4
os : Ubuntu 18.04 Lts

github link to download lf-net: 
https://github.com/vcg-uvic/lf-net-release

pre-trained models download link can be found in Readme.md

first, i try to freeze the model with those lines :

```
 input_graph_def = sess.graph.as_graph_def()

output_node_names=ops['kpts'].op.name+","+ops['feats'].op.name+","+ops['scale_maps'].op.name+","+ops['kpts_scale'].op.name+","+ops['degree_maps'].op.name+","+ops['kpts_ori'].op.name
output_graph_def = graph_util.convert_variables_to_constants(
        sess, # The session
        input_graph_def, # input_graph_def is useful for retrieving the nodes 
        output_node_names.split(",")  
)


output_graph="export/frozen.pb"
with tf.gfile.GFile(output_graph, "wb") as f:
    f.write(output_graph_def.SerializeToString())
tf.train.write_graph(output_graph_def, 'export/', 'frozentxt.pbtxt',as_text=True)
```

(just copy this line on run_lfnet.py line 115)

and try to load it with readNetFromTensorflow from opencv dnn module.

```
Net net = readNetFromTensorflow(pbFilePath);// with only .pb file
```

ending with the following exception :

> cv::Exception'
>     what():  OpenCV(4.1.2-openvino) /home/jenkins/workspace/OpenCV/OpenVINO/build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_graph_simplifier.cpp:90: error: (-212:Parsing error) Input node with name MSDeepDet/strided_slice_8 not found in function 'getInputNodeId'

then i try with pb and pbtxt file

```
Net net = readNetFromTensorflow(pbFilePath, pbtxtFilePath);
```

other exception :

> what():  OpenCV(4.1.2-openvino) /home/jenkins/workspace/OpenCV/OpenVINO/build/opencv/modules/dnn/src/tensorflow/tf_importer.cpp:663: error: (-215:Assertion failed) const_layers.insert(std::make_pair(name, li)).second in function 'addConstNodes'

then i read that i need to use optimize_for_inference too  ( https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/12715)

```
with tf.gfile.FastGFile(output_graph, "rb") as f:
    graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
    graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
    tf.summary.FileWriter('logs', graph_def)

    inp_node = 'Placeholder'
    out_node =  output_node_names.split(",")
    graph_def = optimize_for_inference_lib.optimize_for_inference(graph_def, [inp_node], out_node,
                                                                tf.float32.as_datatype_enum)
    graph_def = TransformGraph(graph_def, [inp_node], out_node, ["sort_by_execution_order"])

    tf.train.write_graph(graph_def, "export/", 'graph_opt.pbtxt', as_text=True)
```

got the following warnings

> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to 'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/block-1/pre-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/block-1/mid-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/block-2/pre-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/block-2/mid-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/block-3/pre-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/block-3/mid-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'MSDeepDet/ConvOnlyResNet/fin-bn/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'SimpleDesc/bn1/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'SimpleDesc/bn2/FusedBatchNorm'
>
> WARNING:tensorflow:Didn't find expected Conv2D input to
>   'SimpleDesc/bn3/FusedBatchNorm'

it seems that i missed something in the input nodes but what ? :/
does anyone can help me?
best regards

Edit : link to tensorboard screen

original model https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/49/3nla.png

frozen model https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/49/p4dz.png

It seems that no entry point is define for ConvOnlyResnet in the frozen model but placeholder is linked to convonlyrestnet in the original graph

am i wrong? How may i fix that?